# Redirect all traffic to bare domain SSL using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl, redirect

I'm trying to redirect all traffic through HTTPS and here's my htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
    RewriteBase /

    RedirectMatch 301 /index.php/(.*)$ /$1

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

Currently here's what's going on,

If the user types in www.domain.com it redirects to: https://domain.com which is good. I would like help in configuring the file so that if the user also types in domain.com they get redirected to https://domain.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be as simple as updating your pattern:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You sir are correct. I updated the pattern as you answered and it did work.
Thank you very much.